# Rails: Create controller instance variables for each entry in the table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instance-variables

In my controller's show method, I am having trouble creating an instance variable for each 'Subject' in my database. The "@pie_correct" variable works, but the problem is in the ".each" loop - I get the error "syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end"  How should I change this?

```
@pie_correct = TestQuestions.where(:correct => true).joins(:test).merge(Test.where(user_id: current_user))

Subject.all.each do |s|
  "@subject_ + #{s.id} + _correct" = @pie_correct.joins(:question).merge((Question.all).joins(:subject).merge(Subject.where(id: s.id)))
end
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the [`instance_variable_set`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set) method:

```
Subject.all.each do |s|
  instance_variable_set "@subject_#{s.id}_correct", @pie_correct.joins(:question).merge((Question.all).joins(:subject).merge(Subject.where(id: s.id)))
end
```

I also believe that you don't need the pluses within your interpolated string.

Comment: Thank you, that works.  I was able to access the instance variables in the view in a similar manner with instance_variable_get("@subject_#{s.id}_correct")

Answer (score 2):

**System**

Props to `Chris Peters` for his answer (which is right)

--

I wanted to raise a point about your system here. Why are you setting multiple `instance variables`?

At a loss for any other reason why, I'd recommend this goes against the [DRY programming principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) of Rails, as well as the Single [Source Of Truth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Source_of_Truth) idea - which means you need to set data once, and use it as you wish.

I would personally set a single instance variable, and loop through that to pull the associative data.

Comment: I'd have to agree with you. At least put all of the values into an array. When answering the question, I could only assume that @user3291025 needed it set that way for some specific reason.

Comment: Thanks Rich, I'm still learning the ropes. I have re-written the controller instance variable as: @subjects = Subject.all, and am looping through the single instance variable in the view.